# Transition Functions for Charts on Tangent Bundle

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Let $(U, \phi) = (U , x^1, ..., x^n)$ and $(V, \psi) = (V , y^1, ..., y^n)$ be overlapping coordinate charts on a manifold $M$. These induce coordinate charts $(TU, \tilde{\phi})$, $(TV, \tilde{\psi})$, with transition maps $\tilde{\psi} \circ \tilde{\phi}^{-1}$ given by 
$$(x^1, ..., x^n, a^1,..., a^n) \mapsto (y^1, ..., y^n, b^1,..., b^n).$$
I computed the Jacobian matrix, and got a $2n \times 2n$ matrix with two blocks, one in the upper left corner and one in the lower right. I have that the determinant is

$$ \det\left({{\partial y_i}\over{\partial x_j}}\right) \cdot \det\left({{\partial b_i}\over{\partial a_j}}\right),$$

but I want to show that it equals $$ \det\left({{\partial y_i}\over{\partial x_j}}\right)^2.$$

How can I finish this proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you only need to see that $\det \big(\frac{\partial b_i}{\partial a_j} \big) = \det \big(\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j} \big)$.

For this, observe that the lower right matrix is just the Jacobian of the linear transformation arising from the change of coordinates. It is $(\phi \circ \psi^{-1})_*$ This might have been obfuscated by writing things out with $a$'s and $b$'s. Remember that those coordinates just refer to the ordinary tangent vectors coming from the choice of coordinates, and they transform exactly as you expect.